# Party and Agreement creation in Biztalk 2010?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am working on a BizTalk 2010 solution dealing with EDI messages. I have a question regarding the creation of parties and agreements.

**Scenario :**

I have 2 parties A and B, A is my host party.
I need to create an agreement between the 2 so that EDI 850 message that is received by Host party A can be processed and an Acknowledgement can be sent to Party B.

**Question:** 
Should I create the agreement from the Host party A or from party B? 
Is there any best practice to create the agreements?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you havo to create an Agreement between A and B, specifyng that Party A is your BizTalk Host, checking the flag "Local BizTalk process messages received..." in Party A properties.

HTH

Massimo